# Connecting to github repository via ssh

Tags: github, ssh

I'm trying to set up ssh to work with my github repository via ssh. I've created and added public ssh key to github and added this key on my machine.
Strange thing is when I do from console

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I'm getting

> Hi my-username-here! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

But when I do

```
ssh -T my-username-here@github.com
```

I'm getting

> my-username-here@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Maybe someone knows what is the problem here?

Comment: "Maybe someone knows what is the problem here?" What _is_ the problem? Can you point to any documentation which suggests `ssh -T my-username-here@github.com` should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "problem" here: any GIt repository hosting service would always block a remote SSH session for a remote user `my-username-here`.

There is no remote account `my-username-here` on the remote Git repository hosting server `github.com`, only `git`.

GitHub then, with the remote user `git`, authenticate you through your public key associated to your GitHub account.
GitLab, BitBucket, Gitea, and other would do the same for SSH URL:

- only remote account `git`
- authentication through a public key associated to the user profile page.